# Twitter bootstrap 3 carousel with fixed background image

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

My feeling is that scrolling background image is not really pleasant so I tried to get a fixed background banner and transparent foreground cycling images. I tried the following solution but in that case, the foreground images are hidden right after the cycling animation:
Any idea to get it working?

```
<html>
<header id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
         <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('banniere2000x400.jpg');"></div>
      <div class="item active">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <img id="menuscreen" src="carouselforeground1.png" alt="Logo"/>
                <p>first image</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <img src="carouselforeground2.png" alt="Logo"/>
                <p>second image</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
           <div class="carousel-caption">
                <img src="carouselforeground2.png" alt="Logo"/>
                    <p>third image</p>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="icon-prev"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="icon-next"></span>
    </a>
</header>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Edited for a working example: Except that I let you choose your own images and it needs botstrap3 installed, I think that should work.

Comment: Might be a z-index issue. Do you have a working example we can see?

Comment: Still no idea to get it working?

Comment: Where is the CSS? Probably best to put this in a Fiddle.

Comment: @Aibrean. the css is the default bootstrap.min.css

Comment: I have never seen `.fill`.

Comment: Not working for me!!

Comment: if its working for anyone please help me with this too .I also want the fixed background carousel so on scrolll the the content will go over the carousel. please help me  @2ndGAB

Comment: @pawankumar I hope my answer will help you, as I did it long time ago and I don't really remember what I did. Sorry to not having answered when I found the solution. But I didn't change the html code so the solution is in the CSS rules.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working but unfortunately, I don't really remember how.
So, as someones wonder how to do, I give here my CSS rules and I hope it will help them.

```
header.carousel .item,
header.carousel .item.active,
header.carousel .carousel-inner {
    height: 100%;
}

header.carousel .fill {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}

#hoverme .fill{
    position: absolute;
}

.carousel-caption{
    font-size: 4em;
    position: absolute;
    top: -11vh;
    left: -10vw;
}

.carousel-caption p{
    position: relative;
    top: -45vh;
    right: -25vw;
}

.carousel-control {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
}
```